# List of executables installed from package

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt

In linux, how can I view all the new executables added to `/usr/bin` after installing a package through `sudo apt-get install <package>`?

In my case specifically, I'm trying to find out which is the main executable to use for the texlive package.

I've tried
`dpkg -L texlive` but that only lists files under `/usr/share` and not `/usr/bin`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This command shows all executable files installed by given package:

```
dpkg -L packagename | xargs file | grep executable
```

If you want to only see executables installed in `/usr/bin`, use:

```
dpkg -L packagename | xargs file | grep ^/usr/bin | grep executable
```

If your package does not list anything under `/usr/bin`, it is possible that it does not have any executables - this is typical for libraries and other helper packages.

Comment: I don't understand. Before installing texlive, I did not have the `tex` executable, among others. Now I do but `dpkg -L` is not showing anything under `/usr/bin/`

Comment: It turns out that I the texlive distribution that comes with Devian/Ubuntu is outdated.